# iOS disable touch event registration

Tags: ios, event-handling, touch, registration

I'm looking for a way to disable/enable all touch event registration in an iOS application, i've searched google and stackoverflow but couldn't find a satisfying answer. Someone around who might happen to know anything about this?

Comment: You mean something like [beginIgnoringInteractionEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW7)? Or is there something special you mean by _registration_?

Comment: sounds like an engaging app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this method to start ignoring all the interaction events:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

And this one to turn event interaction back on:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Comment: Ah well that seems easy :) Thanks!